# Node.js - Express.js URL parameters validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm a node.js/express.js newbie. How can I validate `:id` parameters? I would like to pass only numbers into `:id` parameters. If `:id` is a string or contain once of them, I would to display a 404 error like a zend framework routing http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html

**/routes/users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/:id?/', function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  if(id){
    res.render('single-users', { title: 'Single ' + id });
  }else {
    res.render('users', { title: 'All users' });
  }

});

module.exports = router;
```

I tried to change

`router.get('/:id?/', function(req, res, next)`

to

`router.get('/[0-9]+?/', function(req, res, next)`

but

```
localhost:3000/users/ab/
```

works and display `single-users` page and I want it..

**SOLUTION SUGGESTED BY LUCAS COSTA**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/:id(\\d+)?/', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;

  if(id){
    res.render('single-users', { title: 'Single ' + id });
  }else {
    res.render('users', { title: 'All users' });
  }

});

module.exports = router;
```

or

```
router.get('/:id([0-9]+)?/', function(req, res)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide the regex:

```
router.get('/:id(\\d+)/', function (req, res, next){
    // body
});
```

[Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do the integer-only check inside of the main code block and then return the 404 conditionally?

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  if(id && string.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null)}
    res.render('single-users', { title: 'Single ' + id });
  }else if(string.match(/^[0-9]+$/) == null){
    res.status(404).render('your-404-view');
  }else{
    res.render('users', { title: 'All users' });
  }
});
```